# Notation for Lebesgue Iterated Integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral

For double integrals, usually we will write $\int\dots\,dx\,dy$.

What if we are using Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ notation?

I have seen $\int\dots\lambda(dx)\lambda(dy)$, is this the correct notation? Are there other notations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1,\lambda_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2,\lambda_2)$ are two measure spaces then we form the product space $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2)$ with product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$ then there is a unique measure, say $\lambda_1 \times \lambda_2$ on $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$ such that
$$
\lambda_1 \times \lambda_2 (A_1 \times A_2 ) = \lambda_1(A_1) \lambda_2(A_2)
$$
for $A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2$. And then the abstract result that lets you write 
$$
\int X d(\lambda_1 \times \lambda_2) = \int \left( \int X d\lambda_2 \right)d\lambda_1 = \int \int X d\lambda_2 d\lambda_1
$$
is Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thanks. What if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$? Is it acceptable to write $d\lambda d\lambda$?

Comment: Yeah that would be absolutely acceptable. You would want to include say $\lambda (dx)$ respectively in that case just to keep the order of integration clear

Comment: Basically the $\lambda(dx)\lambda(dy)$ you had in your initial question seems good to me